# Redirect mail to site with no domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, web-hosting, mx-record

So, I'm switching hosting services for a site. I've copied the site over, and I'm fairly confident it'll work fine when I update the DNS.

The issue is, the old site is hosting an email server for about 20 or so people. For now, until I can get all the individual accounts reconnected to the new site's email server, **I'd like to just forward emails to the old site, and preserve the email server on the old one,** perhaps progressively moving the members over.
Fortunately I'm pretty sure all the members are using email forwarding to their own personal emails.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

I looked at MX records, but they can only point to a domain name, which the old site won't have once the domain for it is pointing to my new site.

Comment: Huh? You know you can have as many hostnames as you want in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new domain for the new MX.  Assuming you have `smtp.example.com` as your MX, you could created `smtp2.example.com` or `mx.example.com` for the new MX.

You may want to add the new MX with a different priority until you are ready decommission the old MX.  The priority will control which MX will be used as a first choice by properly behaving MTAs that are sending you mail.

There are a number of methods that can be used to forward mail to the appropriate MX.  It is not unusual for the MX to forward mail for final delivery.